# Bridging wireless and wired networks on Linux box

Tags: nat, wifi

I have the following setup:

modem + router - - - - -Ubuntu box on master mode.........wireless devises. Ubuntu machine connects to Internet on wired network. I've dhcp3-server, masquerading, and wireless card with master mode on Ubuntu box. The issue is Ubuntu connects to the router on NAT. The wireless devises connect to the Ubuntu box on a NAT too (though different). SO my wireless devises are behind two NAT networks. The solution I am looking for is Ubuntu should forward dhcp requests to the modem+router, and Ubuntu should act as a switch or a bridge that allows wireless devises to connect to the wired network. So the modem+router should act a main router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this article, it explains how to bridge a wireless and LAN networks:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BridgingNetworkInterfaces

Don't worry about DHCP relay - that will happen automatically across the bridge. Should you really want to DHCP relay there is a package dhcp3-relay for that but I don't think its what you require here.

Comment: My eth0(wired) gets its ip address over dhcp and some times I use wlan0 on client mode, so I cannot have entries for both in my /etc/network/interfaces file. So is it possible to bridge the interfaces on the fly, perhaps with the ifconfig command?

Comment: Not ifconfig, it would be using brctl. You can setup actions when an interface goes up and down and auto-add to bridges and auto-remove bridges. This setup is sounding more and more complex! Might be easier to buy a $100 router or something to keep it simple?

Answer (score 0):

I did it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/21679/script-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-wireless-accesspoint-on-a-bridge-mode